# sqlalchemy: how to return list of objects joining 3 tables?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

```
@hybrid_method
# @paginate
def investors(self, **kwargs):
    """All investors for a given Custodian"""
    ind_inv_type_id = InvestorType.where(description="Individual").first().id
    inv_query = Investor.with_joined(InvestorAddress, InvestmentAddress, CustodianAddress) \
                        .filter_by(custodians_id=self.id) \
                        .with_joined(Investment) \
                        .filter_by(investor_types_id=ind_inv_type_id)
    investors = Investor.where(None, False, inv_query, **kwargs)

    temp_inv_query = Investor.with_joined(CustodianInvestor, Custodian)\
                             .filter_by(Custodian.id==self.id)
    temp_investors = Investor.where(None, False, temp_inv_query, **kwargs)
    return list(set(investors + temp_investors))
# end def investors



 # @auth.access_controlled
class InvestorAddress(db.Model, EntityAddressMixin):
    # Metadata
    __tablename__ = 'investor_addresses'

    # Database Columns
    investors_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("investors.investors_id"),
                             nullable=False)
    investor = db.relationship("Investor", foreign_keys=[investors_id],
                               backref=db.backref("InvestorAddress"))

# end class InvestorAddress

    class InvestmentAddress(db.Model):
    """This model differs from other EntityAddress Models because it links to either an investor_address or an custodian_address."""

    # Metadata
    __tablename__ = 'investment_addresses'

    # Database Columns
    address_types_id = db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey("address_types.address_types_id"),
        nullable=False)
    address_type = db.relationship("AddressType",
                                   foreign_keys=[address_types_id],
                                   backref=db.backref("InvestmentAddress"))

    investments_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey("investments.investments_id"),
                               nullable=False)
    investment = db.relationship("Investment",
                                 foreign_keys=[investments_id],
                                 backref=db.backref("InvestmentAddress"))

    investor_addresses_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(
        "investor_addresses.investor_addresses_id"))
    investor_address = db.relationship("InvestorAddress",
                                       foreign_keys=[investor_addresses_id],
                                       backref=db.backref("InvestmentAddress"))

    custodian_addresses_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(
        "custodian_addresses.custodian_addresses_id"))
    custodian_address = db.relationship("CustodianAddress",
                                        foreign_keys=[custodian_addresses_id],
                                        backref=db.backref("InvestmentAddress")
                                        )
# end class InvestmentAddress



 class CustodianAddress(db.Model, EntityAddressMixin):
    """Defines the relationship between a Custodian and their addresses."""

    # Metadata
    __tablename__ = 'custodian_addresses'

    # Database Columns
    custodians_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(
        "custodians.custodians_id"), nullable=False)
    custodian = db.relationship("Custodian", foreign_keys=[custodians_id],
                                backref=db.backref("CustodianAddress"))

# end CustodianAddress
```

i have an application and this function is supposed to return a list of 'investors' for a given 'Custodian'. Now when it executes i get an error: "sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: mapper option expects string key or list of attributes". The error comes from the 'join' in the 'inv_query'. 
I have included my 3 models that im using for the Join.

Comment: I have never seen `with_joined` before. I use session-based queries. Also, what is the type of Investor? Is it a Model? Can you provide details or documentation for `with_joined`?

Comment: with_joined come from sqlalchemy-mixins(https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins).
Yes, the investor object is an instance of the investor model. @mad_

Answer (score 1):

As described in the documentation provided by you. [here](https://github.com/absent1706/sqlalchemy-mixins/blob/53e505a23558635cad84fd273eb73529ef064a86/examples/all_features.py)

You should provide string arguments(table names) in with_joined. Given you have defined the relationship

```
Investor.with_joined('investorAddressTable', 'investmentAddressTable, 'custodianAddressTable')
```

In case you can use session then you can query the ORM classes directly like

```
session.query(Investor).join(InvestorAddress).join(InvestmentAddress).join(CustodianAddress).all() # will assume you have set the foreign key properly
```

Comment: yea i tried that but i get another error:sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Can't find property named 'investor_address' on the mapped entity Mapper|Investor|investors in this Query.

im trying to join them using classes and not attributes, idk if that makes sense

Comment: You have to provide the relationship. show your models then only one can help

Comment: i have provided my models that show the relationship between them

Comment: The table name is `investor_addresses` and not `investor_address`